# how to render the whole page?

Tags: jquery, django, rerender

I am using django + jquery to write a html page, the layout of the page is:

```
head (divs)
--------------------------
left (divs) | right (divs)
```

I want to change the whole page (the head divs would be all the same, but the left and right divs would be changed) after I click the head divs(the js would send a post message to the django and get the responsed html).

now I could get the whole new page, but I don't know how to rerender the whole page again? any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with conjunction of [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and adding a new div to contain the content of the site:

```
head (divs)
--------------------------
container div
left (divs) | right (divs)
/container div
```

So you, do something like this.

```
$('#container').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

See the documentation for [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), it let's you loading into specific elements and filter which part of the html to include.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply use [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ?

```
$('#left').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is much ways to do it:

1. you click and django send via ajax the new content and the browser
   will display it
2. you can keep the divs but change some of there
       content/text etc
3. use the function load(), check here:[enter link
       description here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)